# how can i use the UTF8string for the NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have taken char data into database into array. now i want to convert that data into string.

how can i convert array data into NSString.

Comment: An NSArray is an array of objects.  What are the objects in your array? And in what format do you want the string—a concatenation of all the char data? With newlines in between?

Comment: in nsarray i have the NSstring data taken from database and i want to convert that data into NSstring mean into single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `const char *` instance, you can use the `NSString` method [`+ stringWithCString:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJCCGHJ). For example:

```
NSString *_myString = [NSString stringWithCString:_myCharPtr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To put that into an `NSArray*`, you might do the following:

```
NSArray *_myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_myString,nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:<#(const char *)nullTerminatedCString#>]
```